# Can we stop it with the "are there conspiracy theories about X" questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, list-questions

- Are there conspiracy theories about Pakistan? [It's (not?) coup'd by USA regularly.]
- Are there conspiracy theories about India? [It's (not?) an ethnostate.]
- Are there conspiracy theories about Russia? [It's (not?) preparing to invade their neighbors.]
- Are there conspiracy theories about Ukraine? [It's (not?) run by crack addicts.]
- Are there conspiracy theories about Brazil? [TLDR](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2020/09/how-anti-communist-conspiracies-haunt-brazil/614665/).

Yeah, this site needs more listicles of stuff [some] people don't agree with, also tagged as a conspiracy theory. And with answers 50/50 upvoted and downvoted, depending whether someone agrees or not with a controversial statement. "Great subjective" Qs. /end-rant

Comment: Any question that asks "are there examples of [x]?" has always been a terrible question for Stack Exchange, and despite the protestation of many, continues to be a waste of time and space that attracts attention for being controversial or allowing for every person and their animal companion to share whatever they dredge up, rather than interesting and insightful of politics, and of usefulness as part of a high-quality Q&A repository.

Comment: If there's consensus, `/help/on-topic` and/or `/help/dont-ask` can be modified to reflect these questions being outlawed.

Comment: @Nij: IDK if I'd go that far, but when asking about rather nebulous concepts often used derogatorily, they sure are bad. My point is that this kind of Q is not much better than "Are there any fascists in Africa [or some other place]?" If it hits HNQ, you'd get 2-3 good examples max and a long tail of increasingly questionable ones, which people post nonetheless because of the 5:1 UV:DV rep ratio.

Comment: Then, what's left to be ask? Why not have a democratic vote? Is every exchange member included?

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat It's not just (or probably even primarily) the 5:1 ratio that is the main problem, but rather that DV requires 125 rep (and also costs 1,) which is more than the association bonus, while UV requires only 15, which anyone with the association bonus will have. So, people coming from HNQ who have never contributed on Politics before can upvote, but they cannot downvote. Skeptics has the same problem.

Answer (score -4):

My own such question is [*Are there any pro-Israel/anti-Palestinian conspiracy theories?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/84638/38304). In the beginning of the question I provided a list of anti-Israeli/pro-Hamas conspiracy theories - since these are rather common in the discourse on this conflict by one side, it seemed legitimate to ask whether the other side engages in the same game (or if it engages in it to the same extent.) In fact, some such theories do exist (and I probably should write an answer.)

Surprisingly, it was this very part of the question that became an object of an edit war - some users deleting it altogether and claiming that the question would be better, if I simply asked about pro-Israeli conspiracy theories, without mentioning the pro-Hamas ones.

So in principle, I agree that asking out of blue *"Are there any conspiracy theory about X?"* is a bad practice... which should not disqualify all the questions about conspiracy theories, which are a part of political discourse... but many users seem to think otherwise.